# Python open only one directory that starts with specific numbers

Tags: python, directory, startswith

I want to be able to open directories by only typing first digits of the directory number.
In C:/Orders/ I have a couple of directories:

1. 40_0
2. 125_15
3. 4012_0
4. 4040_127
5. 5445_0
6. 4_67

If I type in the input "**4012**" it opens the 4012 directory, but when I type "**4**" it opens **all** directories that start with 4, I need to open only one.

Also, when I type some numbers that don't match any existing directory, it prints("Nothing found") as many times as many directories are in current directory. I have no clue how to solve this.

This is what I tried:

```
os.chdir("C:/Orders")
while True:
    orderNo = input("Type order number: ")
    for filename in os.listdir():
        if filename.startswith(orderNo):
            os.startfile(filename)
        else:
            print("Nothing found.")
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should print the first one that match and print only once in case of non match the "Nothing found."

```
while True:
    orderNo = input("Type order number: ")
    for filename in os.listdir():
        if filename.startswith(orderNo):
            os.startfile(filename)
            break
     else:
         print("Nothing found.")

#Pay attention to where the else is put. This is a nice feature of python (the for else)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. If I input 4 it opens 4012 directory and it also prints Nothing Found.

Comment: It's probably because you did not put the else statement outside the for loop. The else should be at the same indentation level than the for.

Comment: The main problem though is that I need to open only one directory. When I list the directories it lists them in some order and opens the wrong one. If I input "40" iit still opens "4012"

Comment: Well your question was incomplete. You did not specify which one you want to open and I assumed you wanted to open any of them when there are multiple matches. Actually you need to specify which one you want to output first (and you could sort the lists of directories according to this criterium).

Answer (score 0):

you may use:

```
from pathlib import Path
from glob import glob

subfolders = list(map(Path, glob('"C:/Orders/*/')))
name_subfolder = {p.name : p for p in subfolders}


orderNo = input("Type order number: ")
while orderNo != 'exit':
    f = (e for e in name_subfolder.keys() if e.startswith(orderNo))

    try:
        os.startfile(next(f))
    except StopIteration:
        print("Nothing found.")

    orderNo = input("Type order number: ")
```

you are taking all the subfolders and build a dict `name_subfolders` who has as key the name of each `subfolder` and the absolute path, then you can take input and check if any subfolder name starts with a given input if is the case then will open your folder for you if not will give you a not found message